# How to bind/assign one object to another

Tags: c#

I have a class which will have few Properties, these will be part of GridView

```
Class A{
public string LineName{get;set;}
public string Company1{get;set;}
public string Company2{get;set;}
public string Company3{get;set;}
public string Company4{get;set;}
}
```

Also, I have another class which will have

```
Class B{
public string CountryName{get;set;}
public string Region{get;set;}
public string GeoLocation{get;set;}
public string Temperature{get;set;}
...
}
```

Now, I would like to bind these to GridView in this format

```
LineName       |COuntry1  | Country2 |
--------------------------------------
CountryName    |INDIA     | USA
-------------------------------------
Region         |AAAA      | BBBB
------------------------------------
GeoLocation    |XXXXX     | CCCC
------------------------------------
Temperature    |40 C      | 23F
```

Something like this. I am getting Data for Class B as a List like List. Here string is COuntry1, Country2....so my question is how can I bind to Grid View?

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what are you using in your app, is it WinForms, WPF or something web related?

Comment: its a web appl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think instead of have a string properties for your companies in your class A you can use a list of Class B and add a company name attribute to your Class B in your Class it may look like this :

```
Class A
{
public string LineName{get;set;}
public List<B> Companies{get; set;}

public A ()
{
    Companies = new List<B>();
}
}
```

Comment: ok. so If i want to bind it to the GridView then it would be GridView1.DataSource = List<A> right?

Comment: Yup you can try this